# Перерисовка элемента.

Tags: java, awt

Доброго времени суток. Глупый вопрос, но не могу решить. Есть небольшой такой код. При нажатии прямоугольник должен менять координаты, но этого не происходит. Что нужно сделать?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui implements ActionListener {

    int x = 50;
    int y = 200;

    JButton button;
    MyDrawPanel myDrawPanel;
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        myDrawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        button = new JButton("Test");

        frame.setSize(1500, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, myDrawPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        x++;
        y++;
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `должен менять координаты` -- с чего Вы это вязли? Вы лишь только увеличиваете значения переменных. Эти переменные как-то связаны с этим прямоугольником?

Comment: Да, связаны. В методе `g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 200);` они задают положение прямоугольника.

Comment: Они только **первоначально** задают положение прямоугольника.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в метод `actionPerformed(...)` после инкремента переменных строку `MyDrawPanel.setLocation(x, y);`.

Comment: Классно, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы инкрементируете переменные, которые по сути не связаны с `MyDrawPanel`.

Чтобы `MyDrawPanel` перерисовался по новым координатам, в метод `actionPerformed(...)` после инкремента переменных добавьте строку:

```
MyDrawPanel.setLocation(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш метод `paintComponent`, в котором используются переменные `x` и `y`, вызывается только один раз, когда программа отрисовывает свое окно первый раз. 
После того, как вы в методе `actionPerformed` увеличили их значение, перерисовки окна не происходит - для этого нет никакой причины.

Заставьте окно перерисоваться после инкремента переменных, и тогда прямоугольник нарисуется в новом месте. Для этого достаточно добавить одну строчку:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        x++;
        y++;
        frame.update(frame.getGraphics()); // Не забываем обновить окно!!!
    }
```